# escaping url in terraform local-exec

Tags: regex, bash, sed, terraform

let say I have this :-

```
variable "url" {
  value = "https://sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/11111111/my_queue.fifo"
}
provisioner "local-exec" {
command = <<-EOT
  sed -i "s/URL.*:.*/URL: $url/g" "./test.yaml"
EOT
}
```

while the ./test.yaml file would be:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: default
data:
  URL: ""
```

I wonder how to get my `URL: ""` element replaced with an url variable from terraform ? I've tried many times but it returned me regex error. the escaping hell :cry

Comment: I think all you need is `sed -i "s,URL.*:.*,URL: $url,g" "./test.yaml"` (assuming `,` is never present in the `$url`). Or, escape it to be used in `sed` replacement pattern. See [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to set the `url`in your `test.yaml` would be to use [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html). In this case, your `test.yaml` would be:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: default
data:
  URL: "${url}"
```

and the terraform code:

```
variable "url" {
  default = "https://sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/11111111/my_queue.fifo"
}

output "test" {  
  value = templatefile("./test.yaml", {url = var.url})
}
```

Comment: does  this works on .yaml file instead of tf files only? , I've tried doing this but it gave me error
```
A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute
access, specifying the resource name.
```

Comment: @BilalBayasut Yes, it works with `yaml`. The example given in the answer is working one.

Comment: @BilalBayasut No problem. Glad it worked out:-)